# massAssignment using artisan tinker

Tags: mass-assignment, laravel-artisan

I got the following error while trying to insert bulk data in DB table.

```
> D:\wamp\www\laravel>php artisan tinker Psy Shell v0.5.2 (PHP 5.5.12 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman

>>> factory(App\User::class, 100)->create(array('email', 'password', 'firstname','lastname', 'dob', 'phone', 'website', 'role_id')); Invalid ArgumentException with message 'A four digit year could not be found Data missing'.
```

Fillable fields in App\User

```
protected $fillable = ['email', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'dob', 'phone', 'website', 'role_id'];
```

Can someone tell me what might be going wrong?

Comment: Would you please provide your code that leads to this error?

Comment: @Mischback   `>>> factory(App\User::class, 100)->create(array('email', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'dob','phone', 'website','role_id'));`  while trying run from cmd